# CM7 GPS works randomly, no rhyme or reason, is there a fix?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, gps, htc-droid-incredible

I have the Incredible and here are the specs:

CyanogenMod 7.1.0 Stable
Baseband: 2.15.00.07.28

I can't seem to get my GPS to run in a stable manner. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I've installed all the diagnostic GPS apps: GPS Essentials, GPS Status, GPS Test, GPS Fix, and doesn't make a difference. Cleared the AGPS, d/l new AGPS, etc...

When I use any of those, or my speedometer apps - Speedview and UlyssesSpeedometer - the GPS icon doesn't even blink. It's as if it can't hook the GPS command to turn on.

When it does work, it's great, a fix in about 3 seconds and 10 or 11 satellites.

I've run Fix Permissions in Rom Manager, and that seemed to help right away, but nothing since then, and I've ran that after I've installed new apps unrelated to anything GPS, and still to no avail.

How can I fix this to get a stable GPS on my phone?? Any help would be greatly appreciated, so frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone, I think I may have found something, so if anyone is having this problem, hopefully it can help.

I believe it's a problem with google maps. For me, sometimes, when I launch maps and the GPS icon flashes a few times without locking and disappearing, that's when the problem starts.

Well i had the Google Maps Traffic Widgets active, and I would use those all the times and didn't realize it wasn't locking the GPS, But my speedometer apps wouldn't work, or even maps wouldn't work

I uninstalled maps, and reinstalled, didn't help.

This is what i found that works - don't use the traffic widgets, just open maps and look at traffic if you need to.

The second is, if you open maps and GPS doesn't lock, exit maps. Open up GPS Status, let it lock - for me I don't even need to clear or update AGPS info, but you may need to.  Exit GPS Status, not open your speedometer app or Maps, and it should work.

I have been able to 'fix' the GPS issue this way over the last few days with multiple reboots and intalls/uninstalls of maps.

Hopefully this can be helpful or at least a start to troubleshooting. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had this very same issue with my Incredible! I did everything you described and even flashed a newer Radio version to no avail. I got so frustrated I broke down and did a factory reset - for some reason it magically fixed my issue. I know it's the nuclear option here (as well as a popular catch-all answer) but I honestly think it's worth a shot. This also might be an excuse to bump up to CM 7.1.0 Stable.

FWIW I've had various strange and inexplicable issues with Cyanogenmod on my Incredible, this GPS trouble being just one. If you're up for a slight paradigm shift I've come to really like MIUI and haven't run into anything terribly strange (...yet).

*EDIT: Just in case, here are some great instructions for performing a factory reset from the helpful [MIUI HTC Incredible Installation Guide](http://forums.miui.us/showthread.php?12394-GUIDE-HTC-Incredible-Install-GUIDE) (these steps are applicable to performing a factory reset in any ROM as long as you're using ClockworkMod Recovery).*

> 3) Open Rom Manager and select "Reboot into Recovery." (Yes, we're
>   assuming you have already flashed the latest "Clockworkmod Recovery."
>   If you have not, please do so now via Rom Manager by selecting "Flash
>   ClockworkMod Recovery" from the Rom Manager options before trying to
>   reboot into recovery.)
>
> 4) ...from the Main Clockworkmod Recovery
>   menu, select "Backup and Restore." Then Select "Backup." This will
>   create a Nandroid Backup in case anything goes incorrectly during or
>   you get a bad ROM, you can always load your backup and return your
>   phone to EXACTLY the way it was before you began making changes in
>   Recovery. You may also Restore your Backup from here, but only after
>   performing a Full Wipe of your phone to eliminate any trace of the old
>   data that may corrupt your "restore" process. For more info on
>   performing a "Full Wipe," see the next step.
>
> 6) Now to do a clean wipe of your phone. ***Note: At this point you
>   will lose everything on your phone that you have not backed up to an
>   alternative storage space, via cloud, PC, SDcard. This will basically
>   return your phone to a straight out of the box setup.*** Select
>   Factory Wipe/Data Reset from the list of options (On the HTC
>   Incredible, you may move your selector up and down with the trackball
>   or the volume buttons, the press the trackball to enter your
>   selection.) After your selection scroll down through the Nos to the
>   "Yes" and select it, and your phone will begin to clear out its
>   memory. When it completes, you should be back at the menu to Wipe
>   Data/Factory Reset.
>
> 7) After your Full Wipe, scroll down to the "Advanced" menu, and
>   select it. The next list of options should display "Wipe Dalvik
>   Cache." Select it, Scroll down through the Nos to the "Yes" and select
>   it. It should only take a second. This step may be redundant after a
>   full wipe, but if you ever need to "Update" a ROM, its important to
>   know where this option is, so good practice.
>
> 8) Press the "Power" button on the phone to go back to the main
>   Clockworkmod Recovery options.
>
> ...
>
> 13) Select Reboot System Now, and your phone should reboot.

Comment: Crazy! Yeah I've thought about that...doing a complete reset.

When you say 'factory', you mean back to the stock ROM? Or you mean reformatting and reflashing cm7?

I had a typo, I am currently on 7.1.0.

Comment: I mean 'factory reset' as in wiping everything from it an putting it back to the condition it was in when you first flashed your current ROM (I don't mean going back to the stock ROM). See my edit above. As always, make sure to backup your ROM (even if you don't like how it's performing) before making serious changes like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think a reset is probably in the near future, or maybe even a try at the Gingerbread Inc Deck Rom.

I was on MIUI for months until it started sapping data like crazy. I guess it was something to do with the build prop #, not exactly sure. So that's when I switch to CM7. I really liked MIUI though, might go back eventually.

Comment: To each their own. Best of luck!